# Authorizing Google Apps Script to access Drive files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

The code below works fine for getting my own Google+ user attributes:

```
// Google oAuth
function getAuth(service, scopes) {
   var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(service);
   oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken? scope="+scopes);
   oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
   oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
   oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
   oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
   return {oAuthServiceName:service, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
 }

 function test_API_Key() {
    var gPlusAuth = getAuth("plus", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=" + API_KEY;
    var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, gPlusAuth);
    Logger.log(httpResponse);
  }
```

When I use the same approach for accessing metadata about files on my Google Drive, I run into the HTTP error, 403, and "access not configured." Below is the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getFileMetaData(fileId) {
  var driveAuth = getAuth("drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + 
        documentID + "?key=" + API_KEY;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, driveAuth);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Taken from google developer site[1]

At a high-level, all apps follow the same basic authorization pattern:

- Register the application in the Google Developers Console.
- Request that the user grant access to data in their Google account.
- If the user consents, your application requests and receives credentials to access the Drive API.
- Refresh the credentials (if necessary).

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
    var SCOPES = [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      // Add other scopes needed by your application.
    ];
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth